# PHP. When including file it add symbol '?' from nowhere!

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, include, echo

I have a trouble with include function, here is a problem:
i have index.php with a string:

```
<td style="width: 62604px; height: 41px" class="style36"> <?  include('title.php');?></td>
```

here is title.php:

```
<?php
echo 'some crazy stuff!';
?>
```

it doesn't matter what inside of this file!Because, when I'm running the index.php script: it always shows me 'п»' symbol it`s representation of '?' in windows-1251 charset.
So the result page is:

```
<td style="width: 62604px; height: 41px" class="style36"> п» some crazy stuff</td>
```

Comment: Stop using short open tags

Comment: You got a Byte Order Mark at the beggining of your file and that's the character you're seeing. Probably because your file is UTF-8. Using Notepad++ you can remove it under "Format" Menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a Byte Order Mark. Your included file is encoded in UTF8 with BOM at the beginning. These are three bytes that say if multibyte character are stored from highest byte to lowest or the other way round.

Anyway, you need to get rid of it. You can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for example. Open the file in it, go to `Encoding` menu, select `Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`